# How to get width and height of a binary tree, provided its root node?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

From root Node.
Widht = it would be the level with more nodes
height = is the total of levels the root node has

In next example it has 3 levels (height=3)
and the last level has 3 nodes then widht=3
how can i get this values programmatically?

[image]

this is my code but always return 1 in height and 1 in widht

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in); //Creación de un objeto Scanner

    int valor=0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese el primer valor");
    valor=Integer.valueOf(entradaEscaner.nextLine());

    Nodo nodo = new Nodo(valor);
    Nodo anterior=null;
    boolean continar=true;
    while(continar){

        System.out.println("Nodo actual "+nodo.valor+(anterior!=null?" Nodo anterior "+anterior.valor:""));
        System.out.println("Eliga una opcion");
        System.out.println("1)Ingresar valor izquierda");
        System.out.println("2)Ingresar valor derecha");
        System.out.println("3)Regresar Nodo anteriormente seleccionado ");    
        System.out.println("4)No ingresar mas datos terminar arbol");    


        switch(Integer.valueOf(entradaEscaner.nextLine())){
        case 1:  
            System.out.println("Eligio el Nodo de la izquierda Ingrese un numero");
            anterior=nodo;
            nodo.izquierda= new Nodo(Integer.valueOf(entradaEscaner.nextLine()));
            nodo=nodo.izquierda;
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Eligio el nodo de la derecha Ingrese un numero");
            anterior=nodo;
            nodo.derecha= new Nodo(Integer.valueOf(entradaEscaner.nextLine()));
            nodo=nodo.derecha;
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Eligio el nodo anteriormente seleccionado ");
            if(anterior!=null)
            {
                Nodo actual=nodo;
                nodo=anterior;
                anterior=actual;


            }else{
                System.out.println("Pero no existe un nodo anterior, sigues en el nodo actual "+nodo.valor);

            }
            break;

        default:
            continar=false;
            break;

        }

    }


    if(determinarAlturaAnchura(nodo))
        System.out.println("El tamaño de la anchura y altura es el mismo");
    else 
        System.out.println("El tamaño de la anchura y altura NO es el mismo");

}


/*

    /*
    Haciendo uso del proceso del árbol binario y recibiendo como parámetro este proceso, 
    determine si la anchura de dicho árbol es igual a su altura
    */

//recibe un nodo (arbol)
static  boolean determinarAlturaAnchura(Nodo node){


    int tamañoAncho=getMaxWidth(node); 
    int tamañoAlto=height(node);
    System.out.println("El tamaño maximo del ancho es "+tamañoAncho);
    System.out.println("El tamaño maximo del alto es "+tamañoAlto);

    return tamañoAncho==tamañoAlto;



}


/* funcion para conseguir el ancho maximo*/
static int getMaxWidth(Nodo node) 
{
    int maxWidth = 0;
    int width;
    int h = height(node);
    int i;

    /* consigue el tamaño de cada nivel y lo compara con el maximo tamaño */
    for (i = 1; i <= h; i++) 
    {
        width = getWidth(node, i);
        if (width > maxWidth)
            maxWidth = width;
    }

    return maxWidth;
}

/* consigue el tamaño de un nivel */
static  int getWidth(Nodo node, int level) 
{
    if (node == null)
        return 0;

    if (level == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (level > 1)
        return getWidth(node.izquierda, level - 1)
                    + getWidth(node.derecha, level - 1);
    return 0;
}


/* consigue el tamaño de niveles de un arbol*/
static  int height(Nodo node) 
{
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        /* calcula el tamaño de cada arbol */
        int lHeight = height(node.izquierda);
        int rHeight = height(node.derecha);

        /* usa el mas largo*/
        return (lHeight > rHeight) ? (lHeight + 1) : (rHeight + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, if you need this info, you should keep track of it whenever you insert into the tree.  Otherwise you will have to iterate through the entire tree to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, one request is to have one method for get the width and height

Comment: The way you construct your tree in the main method is error prone. Try the input sequence: 1, 2, 1, 3, 4. You will get a height of 2 and a width of 1, which is correct. You need to pass the root Node to the functions. With your code, you can not go back to the root Node. Save a reference to a first Node. Please rework your code and edit your question if you need further help.

Comment: Even without knowing Spanish(?) I can tell you there is something wrong with the way you construct the tree. The loop allows you to 1) add the first child of a node 2) add the second child of a node or 3) swap the last child created and the node it was added to as target for adding the next child. This means you can only traverse up one level in the tree, which makes adding both `1` and `6` in the given tree impossible and also means you cannot "go back" to `5` to get the width/height for this node.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getWidth()` has got many problems:

- You are passing the `root` node for all the different levels in the tree.
- You are not keeping track of the number of nodes already traversed at that level.
- Calling `getWidth()` under a loop.

Make changes as shown below, and print the *maximum* value in `count` array as maxWidth:

```
void getWidth(Nodo node, int level, int count[]) 
{
    if (node != null) 
    {
        count[level]++;
        return getWidth(node.izquierda, count, level + 1)
             + getWidth(node.derecha, count, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Method `height(Nodo node)` looks OK, there must be some problem in your node-insertion-code.